# Optimize Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, debugging, design-patterns

I have a problem with the speed of page loading.

Now it takes about 7 seconds to load the pages and 2~3 seconds is Django processing.

Obvious thing to blame is my lack of knowledge of architecture, execute average 50 queries, as shown by "Django debug tool bar" when accessing the pages but most of the queries are like "yesterday`s snapshot(group by something)" or "daily snapshot(group by something) before yesterday" and doesn't have to be updated each time.

I am coming out of idea using memory caching or create new table for prepare-possible type of data.

Is there any convention or Design Pattern for this kind of issue?

sample queries are these( I believe they must not query each time on yesterdays data or last month`s data):

```
SELECT `sample_salestarget`.`id`, `sample_salestarget`.`country_id`,                    `sample_salestarget`.`year`, `sample_salestarget`.`month`, `sample_salestarget`.`sales`  FROM `sample_salestarget` WHERE (`sample_salestarget`.`country_id` = "abc" AND `sample_salestarget`.`month` = 8 AND `sample_salestarget`.`year` = 2012 )

SELECT `sample_dailysummary`.`id`, `sample_dailysummary`.`country_id`, `sample_dailysummary`.`date`, `sample_dailysummary`.`pv_day`, `sample_dailysummary`.`pv_week`, `sample_dailysummary`.`pv_month`, `sample_dailysummary`.`active_uu_day`, `sample_dailysummary`.`active_uu_week`, `sample_dailysummary`.`active_uu_month`, `sample_dailysummary`.`active_uu_7days`, `sample_dailysummary`.`active_uu_30days`, `sample_dailysummary`.`paid_uu_day`, `sample_dailysummary`.`paid_uu_week`, `sample_dailysummary`.`paid_uu_month`, `sample_dailysummary`.`sales_day`, `sample_dailysummary`.`sales_week`, `sample_dailysummary`.`sales_month`, `sample_dailysummary`.`register_uu_day`, `sample_dailysummary`.`register_uu_week`, `sample_dailysummary`.`register_uu_month`, `sample_dailysummary`.`pay_count_day`, `sample_dailysummary`.`pay_count_week`, `sample_dailysummary`.`pay_count_month`, `sample_dailysummary`.`total_user`, `sample_dailysummary`.`inv_access_uu`, `sample_dailysummary`.`inv_sender_uu`, `sample_dailysummary`.`inv_accepted_uu`, `sample_dailysummary`.`inv_send_count`, `sample_dailysummary`.`memo`, `sample_dailysummary`.`first_charge_uu` FROM `sample_dailysummary` WHERE `sample_dailysummary`.`date` = 2012-09-07 AND `sample_dailysummary`.`country_id` = "abc" )
```

Comment: I assume you're letting Django do all of the queries for you? Because `group by` can be pretty slow at times, in general

Comment: This is *nowhere* near enough information to help you from, but I can say that you're making the mistake countless others make. The load times presented by the debug toolbar are only relevant in context with other views or other iterations of the same view, *not*, and I repeat *not* relevant for the overall true speed of your page. The debug toolbar slows down the processing and rendering *significantly*. A page that takes 7 seconds to load with debug toolbar, might take less than a second without it.

Comment: please show some example of queries you're making, there is a lot you can do to speed up django if you know what you're doing

Comment: charlieng,John,Jharwood,
Here is the sample queries taken from django tool bar.

Comment: Chris,
Thanks for you advice.However,my firebug shows 2~3 seconds　on rendering which seems to correspond with django tool bar`s result.Apache or network log show they respond reasonably quick time .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Memcached](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#memcached) can really speed things up for you. However, that does come with it's problems. You have to be extra careful on dynamic pages about explicitly invalidating caches whenever required.

Along with Memcached, try [johnny-cache](http://packages.python.org/johnny-cache/) which does a very good job of caching your django ORM queries

Also, make use of [Django's session variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) as far as possible. (Try the cached_db session engine if you're using Memcached.) You could save objects (like your user profile settings) which stay consistent throughout a session. This way you're reducing the number of sql calls again.

And if you really really need quick pageloads.. Maybe try loading your page and then asynchronously calling your sql statements using [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) and load your results in an AJAXy manner.

Comment: Thanks.I will try the caching,session middle ware,and Celery(my favorite)!

Answer (score 2):

If this is a production application to be exposed to the internet, and you can't reduce the number of queries you make then you should at least reuse the answers, I would suggest using django's built in DB cache to store database results in ram using memcached. If this is a local app then i would suggest django's ram based cache. the reason for this is memcached is able to be scaled a lot further than django's but django's requires little setup

[Caching for Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs)

Comment: Thanks.My application is exposed on internet.Can I use redis instead of memcached for DB cache?

Comment: Never used Redis, but Django supports memcached out of the box.